# off-topic site list?

Tags: support, flags, off-topic

If I found a question on SO that may should live in another site, I can "flag" then say "it does not belong here". However, the site list proposed only show few  sites of the network.

For example, if I want to suggest a moderator to move a question to sharepoint.stackexchange.com, what is the proper way to do this ?

Concrete example with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439227/listfielditerator-update-item-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) is not a duplicate, but it is related, and Jeff's answer to it also answers your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The list only comprises the most likely migration candidates. This is to avoid the popup page being inundated with all the sites of the SE network. However, the list could use a bit of expanding (lots of WP related no coding questions on SO)

The correct procedure for this is to flag the question for moderator notice and add a little note.

Comment: but when you flag the question, there's no text field to justify the flag... should I comment the question in this way ?

Comment: You need to select the `it needs ♦ moderator attention` option and select `other`. Not the `it doesn't belong here` option.

Comment: I think a far better overall solution would be to have the last option reserved for 'Other' where it prompts from a pop up of the entire list (similar to how tags work).  Unfortunately I doubt I can enter this as either an RFE style question (given it would be a duplicate of this question) or as an answer, since an RFE does not answer the OP's question.  Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong in my reasoning (as is often the case).

Comment: Is it really that hard to have drop down menu that can list all of SE sites, or perhaps a search box? If people can select the exact site that a question should be moved to it, it can then be taken as the basis for later features, such as automigration if enough be people vote for it. I agree that listing the most likely is good, as for the most there are only a few sites that you would want to migrate to.