# Could we have Code Review be one of the list of off-topic closing options?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

I just voted to close [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791718/request-for-a-code-quality-check-on-an-integer-to-string-function-written-in-c) which belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com - someone has indicated this in a comment but it would seem like an obvious candidate for adding to the list of default "belongs on" sites in the "off topic" dialog box.

Comment: I don't think this specific FR should be considered a dupe of the very general question people are closing as.

Comment: If the question is worth asking on CodeReview, they'll go to CodeReview to ask it after it has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of SE sites used as suggestion for a migration is five, and Stack Overflow already list five different SE sites.
Those sites are the ones that have more probability to be used as migration. If you think the question should be migrated to a completely different site, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Consider that a normal migration doesn't work if none of the tags used from the question exists in the site where the question should be migrated; in that case, the question is simply closed as off-topic. Moderators can force the question to be migrated, in such case, though.

Comment: Maybe it's time to rethink the 5 limit.

Comment: Or fix the problem by making users more aware of the other sites that might be more appropriate?

Comment: @Lance Roberts, I agree with this. I didn't realise that 5 was a hard limit, although having read the linked "dupes" I do now see why. I liked the suggestion someone made of having five options and then a "more..." to select from the full list.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious site to migrate that whole category of questions from Stack Overflow.  Maybe it's time to rethink the 5 site limit for off-topic closing, or have a "more..." list, or something else.

**BUT** in this case Code Review is still in Beta, and there's no sense in adding it to the list until its a full Stack Exchange site.