# Easier path to close vote/migration "vote" for questions that "don't belong here"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

I have recently seen yet another question where I thought "hey, that should better be at codereview", and then went to close->offtopic->other site -> uhm, there was no codereview. And then I was unsure on what to do next. So I left it as-is, since it otherwise felt like a fine question. I shortly considered flagging it for moderator attention, but ultimately didn't. codereview is just an example, it can happen for a lot of other sites.

Reading various questions and comments here suggested that this would have been the right thing to do, but a lot also expressed they felt hesitant for various reasons. Among them are -- and I feel a little of them all too -- the following:

- Already went what was thought to be the proper route to close the question; then got stuck and didn't want to go back through the interface to close.
- Hesitant to flag for moderator attention because moderators seem to be responsible for "real" issues, and this doesn't seem to be such a big deal.
- Hesitant to flag for moderator attention, because they are generally careful with flagging, and want to generally avoid having "declined" flags in their flagging history (It seems that to those people, having it declined feels like having done something wrong)

There are some question that deal with this, or similar issues, and have sometimes been declined, or as answers there you can find wishes for a new feature.

- [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/) would want to add more sites, which would remove the problem only for those added.
- [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/) is a trigger to revise the list, but it is probably not formalized how/when this is being done.
- [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022) is intresting, but error prone (when the OP chose the wrong site, its likely he also chose wrong tags)
- [more flexible offtopic migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128617) asks for being able to manually specify the url to migrate to
- [Better "Flag for migration" interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210545) is similar, though I don't think we should offer a list of possible sites to migrate to, but rather add a bullet point, and have it say "instead of vote, flag for moderator attention with: [textbox]"

Some people here suggest that questions should just be closed as offtopic and not migrated at all; we currently have the possibility to migrate, and I think unless those people get the migration feature removed alltogether, we should improve migration as good as we can.

It might also be a good idea to consider making this a double action: vote for close as offtopic, and at the same time mark for moderator attention. In that case, the voter clearly states "hey, this doesn't belong here", but he flags for moderator attention too.

### tl;dr

I propose that we add a last bullet point, just almost as proposed in [Add "Flag as Other" checkbox to "Vote to Close as Off-Topic" dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog/187824#187824) and [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration#140755)

**With the (imho) important difference that it should be made more clear that this is a flagging for moderator attention**, so it should be set apart from the rest, visually, and the text should probably say: "Flag for moderator attention" and the textbox should be pre-filled with the text "Please migrate this to ". A text below should say something like "This counts as a close vote with the reason: "

Image from those answers is:

[image]

Comment: I *always* motivate why a question should be migrated somewhere. Places like codereview are not eligible to be listed as they are still in Beta (meaning that they are still working out what exactly *is* on-topic there), others because too much crap was being migrated. E.g. the fact that migration is harder is *deliberate*.

Comment: I don't think that automating the migration-by-moderator path is going to be very much welcomed by the moderators either, they have enough flags to process as it is. I still have an open 'migrate to CR' flag from over a week ago, I don't think the moderators want to add to that backlog any more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In the proposed way, nothing will really change in the way the choice whether or not something is to be migrated is being done. The vote system will still have just the list, the others is in the hands of moderators. The double action will make it easier for people to express what they mean, and the easier access path to the moderator will help people to raise their voice, who otherwise will be silent.I can see that moderators don't want even more work, but I think "burying contact options deep in the interface" (exaggerating there a lot) is not a useful option to achieve that

Comment: @PlasmaHH you obviously put a lot of thought into this post, but since your feature request is little more than "we should do what was proposed here", how is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I find the other(s) not to be sufficient because of 1) they don't at the same time do a close vote *and* moderator flag and 2) the proposed/mentioned gui doesn't really emphasize it being "just" a moderator flag, but rather make it appear as if the text box should just contain the site to migrate to, rather than being a full standard moderator flag text (hence my idea of pre-filling it with some text instead of having the textbox being part of a sentence)