# Why does the "off topic"-flagging-UI not include all SE-sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, flags, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

The window to flag a question for being off-topic only includes a small subset of SE-sites. Why not include all sites (or all sites potentially relevant to the respective site), so that the question can be correctly attributed? A common choice for an off-topic flag on the SO-site would be "Android Enthusiasts", for example, as a lot of non-programming Android questions are being asked on SO.

Comment: Where do you stop? English language? German? Judaism?

Comment: Is it okay to program Ruby on the Sabbath?