# There should be more sites to select on of topic close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

I just found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178819/some-math-and-geometry-questions which belong to math but you can't select math from close->off_topic, there should be more options. Tt can be autocomplete or drop down with all stack exchange sites.

Comment: You can flag a question for moderator attention and leave them a note saying the question is better off on Math.