# Description of close and closing tags in meta

Tags: support, tags, vote-to-close, meta

The [close](/questions/tagged/close) and [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) on meta do not have wiki summary yet.

I am too new to decipher anything about them. Please add a summary or remove these tags.

While searching for a question in my mind the first thing was to search for the [closed](/questions/tagged/closed) / [close](/questions/tagged/close). Now I have seen that a tag [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) exists and I found [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) under that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[closing](/questions/tagged/closing) was just a terrible tag to begin with. I've retagged all the questions that had it, a lot of which went **all over the place**, a couple of which were not related to the closing process at all. I imagine the [close](/questions/tagged/close) tag will be just as bad.

I believe that [close](/questions/tagged/close) should be synonymized with [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) as the majority of questions go there, but **please manually retag all the questions there first** to make sure they all end up in the right place in the end. The first tag was a mess so it's safe to assume this one will be as well (and I'm tired and don't feel like going through that one at the moment).

Comment: I have retagged some of them, but I don't think I have the rights to define tag synonyms.