# provide more site proposals for Off Topic flagging

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

### Issue

When raising a flag for off-topic questions, the list proposing the available stackexchange websites for migrating the question is as follows:

[image: off topic flag options]

I believe the list is lacking, as many times i ran into the occasional off-topic question which its appropriate site for hosting is not on the list, like those belonging on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, for instance.

### Proposal

My offer is to add another option, describing all other relevant stackexchange websites, as the last entry in the list, and keep it collapsed until chosen, or perhaps provide an Ajax-like autocompletion mechanism that resembles the Exact Duplicate proposals view:

[image: off topic autocomplete]

Comment: This question is getting almost as bad as the "requrie downvoters leave a comment" series.

Comment: huh? what do you mean by that? leave a comment and explain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this functionality already...it's explicitly restricted to moderators because most users aren't aware what is or isn't off topic on the destination site, they're just going by the name (we see this with inappropriate flags as well, which is why the moderator gate mechanism exists).

As for the argument "well, how do moderators know what's on topic everywhere?" good question, they don't.  That's why migrations are often discussed on the global mod chat room before shipping over something they're unsure about.

Comment: Can't you replace: _"Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems"_  what ever it is, with programmers and code-review?

Comment: @gdoron - we choose the most 5 common migration targets...if that changes over time as sites evolve, meta is the place to propose a change and we'll run the numbers to see if that's supported, and if so make the change...we've done it several times before.  Keep in mind though the sites available to migrate to is specific *to a site*, and the OP didn't even mention which site he's trying to migrate *from*.  Since we're discussing SO, it should be noted **a lot of crap was thrown to those sites**, they are *very* intentionally *not* direct migration options.

Comment: @gdoron Programmers getting off SO's migration list was something the Programmers community was asking for, for quite some time. When it finally happened, we partied all night (well, at least I did ;).

Comment: @YannisRizos. Ohh, I thought _programmers_ is the recycle bin of SO, you know something like `> dev/null`, I didn't know it really has a community... ;)

Comment: How about letting users vote to migrate question to site where they have sufficiently good reputation (and thus should know what is on-topic)?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - that's great in theory, but in practice the set of users matching that criteria for almost all sites is incredibly small, overlayed with the percentage seeing *that* question and you'd end up with almost never enough users to satisfy the close rules.

Comment: @NickCraver, it is still greater that very limited amount of moderators. Additionally, votes from those "trusted on both sites" users can be displayed in same view where moderators view migration flags right now, but prominently highlighted, so moderator would know that there's knowledgeable user  support (or two, or three) behind that move, allowing him to make decision quicker.