# Why are off-topic migration options so limited? Should more specific SE tech sites be more visible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

StackExchange has grown a lot, and I routinely see StackOverflow questions that are much better suited for some of the other sites.  Right now, the options for migrating off-topic StackOverflow questions are : Meta; ServerFault; SuperUser; TeX; and, DBA.  In addition to questions that belong on these sites, I have routinely seen questions that would be better suited for a host of other SE sites, such as: Programmers, Pro Webmasters; Mathematics; Ubuntu; IT Security; Cross Validated; Word Press; Code Review; User Experience; Software Quality Assurance; Salesforce; and, Theoretical Computer Science.  At present, my way of addressing these questions involves either: flagging for moderator attention; or, ignoring them.  I usually end up doing the latter, but I think this behavior would change if I didn't have to spend time writing a custom note explaining the problem.

Is there a reason that we only have the 5-specified options available for migration recommendations?  It seems to me like allowing a smoother integration between closely related StackExchange sites would enhance the health of the smaller, more-specific sites and also, create a canonical source of information.  At present, it feels like StackOverflow acts as the default place where all tech-related questions get dumped.  While I'm assure this helps with StackOverflow's individual site popularity, it probably weakens the value in having such a large network.

On another note, I think it's possible that many StackOverflow users don't know about all the more specific SE tech sites.  I know that I personally found about Programmers and ServerFault by seeing the "This question has been migrated" tag in pointer questions.  This makes me think that adding additional migration options under "vote to close" would help increase awareness of the more appropriate places to post.

Another idea that I have for increasing visibility on would involve augmenting the suggestive behavior in writing questions.  I imagine this would work in the same way that the word "best" gets associated with "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.", the word "Drupal" could be associated with "Did you know that [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) is a StackExchange dedicated to Drupal?  Your question might fit better there."  The same kind of associations could be added for other keywords (e.g. IIS and Apache might be indicators for ServerFault migration).  Is there a downside to something like this that I am not seeing?

### Update

I don't think this is an exact duplicate, because the scope of the question is wider than [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) .  That being said, I have extracted the unique parts of this question and placed them in a separate question at : [Should specific SE tech sites be more visible on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149003/should-specific-se-tech-sites-be-more-visible-on-stackoverflow)