# Should specific SE tech sites be more visible on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, vote-to-close, off-topic

Stack Exchange has grown a lot and has a bunch of sites whose content ends up on Stack Overflow.  These include, but are not limited to: Meta; Server Fault; Super User; TeX; DBA; Programmers, Pro Webmasters; Mathematics; Ubuntu; IT Security; Cross Validated; Word Press; Code Review; User Experience; Software Quality Assurance; Salesforce; and, Theoretical Computer Science.  I think the reason these questions end up on Stack Overflow is because users are unaware of the alternatives.  It seems to me like allowing a smoother integration between closely related Stack Exchange sites would enhance the health of the smaller, more-specific sites and also, create a canonical source of information.

An idea that I have for increasing visibility of would involve augmenting the suggestive behavior in writing questions. I imagine this would work in the same way that the word "best" gets associated with "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.", the word "Drupal" could be associated with "Did you know that Drupal Answers is a Stack Exchange dedicated to Drupal? Your question might fit better there." The same kind of associations could be added for other keywords (e.g. IIS and Apache might be indicators for Server Fault migration). Is there a downside to something like this that I am not seeing?

Comment: One of the problems I see is not so much in the displayed information, but in the users. A suggestion should be just that. A suggestion. It should still be upon the user to see for themselves if the suggestion fits. But if my experience with users is anything to go by, I would not be surprised if it results in off-topic questions being asked with the argumentation "But the system told me to ask it here". I can't judge of course how often that would happen.