# Ask Ubuntu as off-topic migration slot

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, migration, askubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

Nowadays on Stackoverflow there seem to be a lot Ubuntu-related questions, mostly related to installation of various IDEs and programming languages. They don't really fit into Stackoverflow category and often getting negative votes and they seem like easy questions for Ask Ubuntu fellows.

I know about the "don't make me think" and question [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration).

But maybe we should reconsider to make these migrations (via proper flagging) easier. With newer versions of Ubuntu including OpenJDK instead of Oracle Java and various PPAs with libraries, IDEs and programming languages there are probably a lot more questions about Ubuntu than ever (just look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=ubuntu). It isn't trivial for people flagging to choose if they belong on Superuser or Serverfault from the available options.

Comment: I've seen that question and I'm only asking about Ubuntu because there are a lot of those questions nowadays. I've mentioned that question in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be better asked on meta Ask Ubuntu, not here. They should decide first if they would even want to accept migrations. Which, for most sites, are less than desirable due to high numbers of rejections and questions that end up closed.

Right now it [looks likely](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/should-server-fault-be-removed-from-stack-overflows-migration-list) that ServerFault will want to be removed from migrations due to the high rejection rate and poor questions that get voted for migration.

Comment: Serverfault is directed at system administrators, they hold really high standards when it comes to questions, demanding a lot of knowledge and great insight. Ask Ubuntu is more casual user friendly and questions there are usually easier (also they apply to a lot more people than server related questions). Questions about Ubuntu on Stackoverflow might fit better on Ask Ubuntu. Also I think that some 'wrong' migrations are due to fact that people migrate typical Ask Ubuntu questions to Serverfault.

Comment: Also I will ask this question on meta Ask Ubuntu, thanks for the answer.