# Add instructions about migrating to other sites to the close dialog

Tags: feature-request, migration

I keep encountering questions that don't belong on Stack Overflow, or on any of the sites listed on the `Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` window.  I saw [Jeff's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/226157), and I think what he said would be worth mentioning on the `Migration` page because it's not obvious what you should do in that situation. For example, it would list the 5 options, then say:

> If you feel strongly a question belongs on a site that isn't listed,
>   then flag for moderator attention.

Or does this conflict too much with "Don't make me think"?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I want the comment on the page. It could point to the first (flagging) page because it has the flag for moderator attention option it, which has the text input box for custom requests.

Comment: Your title somewhat different compared to what I think you are asking.  You want to just add a comment to point the flagger to a using custom flag to move it elsewhere other than the listed options?

Comment: @psubsee2003 No, I just want the comment on the page. It could point to the first (`flagging`) page because it has the `flag for moderator attention` option it, which has the text input box for custom requests.

Comment: Finally, a "not enough migration targets" that doesn't just propose more.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was trying to confirm.  When I read your title, I originally thought you wanted to add more options to the list (which is a common request).  You might want to make your title more descriptive.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Feel free to change it; SO is community moderated :)