# Less sites to close questions as migrations

Tags: feature-request, migration

Today I came across a question on SO and I clearly know that the question belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). I thought that I should close the question as it belongs to another site. However there are very less sites in the dialog.

[image]

So is there any chance that it could get migrated?

Comment: @Emracool My question is about the less options in that dialog.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189570, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190430

Comment: @Sri Yeah, I was caught by pressing enter when searching for the duplicate, which automatically submits a close vote, even when it doesn't make sense to. I retracted the close vote.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking why there are few sites in that list? Are you asking to add codereview to that list? Are you asking for a mod to migrate that question?

Comment: @Mat I was asking to add more options to that list.

Comment: Then please edit your question to say that. And that's a dup, there's tons of posts about why this is limited to five sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe a question should be migrated to a stackexchange site that is not on that list. You should flag the post and use the other option to explain where you think it belongs and why.

If a moderator agrees with you, They'll migrate it.