# Very few options under Migration Flag?

Tags: support, flags

When I am flagging questions, I have tried to use the site migration flag(This post belongs on another Stack Exchange site), but I never have any options.  Every time I click on that option, it only gives me one or sometimes 2 options and it's never one that would actually work.  Is there a reason for this?  I always thought it was only going to give me options for sites that I'm registered at, but it doesn't even give me all of those options.  Is there a way to fix this or is this just how it is?

Comment: See also: [More options when flagging for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/262755)

Comment: Sorry, I posted this on another SE site and didn't see these duplicates, thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: If you think there's a site that should be added to the migration dialog, make the case for it on the per-site Meta.