# Can we allow close voter to suggest other SE site

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

Currently, if I am voting to close a question as belonging on another SE site there is a fixed list, *presumably auto-generated*, of which other sites to choose from but often that list doesn't include the site that I know would actually welcome the question.

While the automatic selection of sites could be improved why not simply have a select other button that allows the close voter, *with sufficient reputation*, to pick any SE site and adds it to the list for subsequent voters to second. *It may not be a bad idea to require that the site suggester have a minimum reputation threshold on the referred site as well.*

A recent example was [LGPL build tool can be used to for commercial software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/354718/lgpl-build-tool-can-be-used-to-for-commercial-software) which I believed belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ but when I select Close->Off Topic->Other Site the options I was given were:
[image]

Neither of which do I think to be as good a fit.

Note that I am aware of ["More options"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205) but differ in that I am making a concrete proposal of how to address the issue where to refer misplaced questions rather than a general request for "more options".

Comment: Use *in need of moderator intervention*.

Comment: My impression is that _in need of moderator intervention_ is for more serious events than "this is on the wrong site but the one I think it should be on isn't on the list" allowing users with enough reputation to vote to close to add to the list of suggested sites to take it to shouldn't require moderator intervention IMHO.

Comment: I think specifying other sites would be very useful - there's a wide range of sites as Stack Exchange continues to grow.

Comment: @PolyGeo that question was a more general add "more options" and was declined.