# Limited options for migrating questions to other sites

Tags: discussion, migration

Often when it seems that a question is more appropriate to be asked on another site, the flagged options presented are insufficient for the proper site. For example, I found a [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/74489/does-order-of-data-points-matter-for-approximating-auc-with-unit-time-steps?noredirect=1#comment79217_74489) on the Data Science site that I thought would be more appropriate on the Computational Science site. However, when I tried to flag it to move it, the only site I could suggest was the Data Science Meta site.

Why are there limited options for migrating questions? I've noticed it on Stack Overflow as well. Is it a reputation privilege? Is it just certain sites? It seems this question has been discussed [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) but the problem still exists or at least the migration instructions are still unclear.

Comment: Choosing a site for a post is not trivial.  Checking that the post is on-topic and searching for an existing answer to avoid dupes takes effort.  Mods and privileged users should not be tasked with spending volunteer time on this work and curators should not have to clear up badly-migrated questions.  The OP posted to an inappropriate site to start with, and the OP should do any migration by cut/pasting to another site.  Note: cut, not copy.  Poor migrations have resulted in site users asking for their siteto be removed from the migration list - we should not make this situation worse:(