# Site list for "It does not belong here" flag, proposed changes

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration-path-request

I have seen [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96013/off-topic-site-list) [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites) regarding the site list for the "it does not belong here flag."

Stack Exchange has something like 76 sites up and running now, with more and more sites coming online regularly.  Obviously, not everyone is going to be a member of all 76+ Q&A sites and, further, most users aren't even going to know of the existence or breadth of the site list.  However, limiting the target list of sites to an arbitrary five is going to be less and less accurate as the network continues to grow.

I think that sites are related in two ways, by user membership and by topic.  I don't know if there is a loose categorization of the sites behind the scenes (e.g. movies, music performance, etc in 'entertainment.')  If that does exist, though, when flagging a question for migration, I'd like to see three options:

1. The sites that I belong to.
2. The sites that are loosely related to the site I'm on.
3. All sites.

The theory being that, if I have knowledge of where it needs to go, then there is a decent likelihood that I am a member of that site as well.  If I'm not a member, then the asker probably didn't know about the other sites (there are what, like 10-15 development-related sites.)  And lastly, if it's not related (e.g. diy to cooking) then at least it's still findable.

I recognize it's easy enough to just add a note to the mods for the flag, but that's a terrible user experience right now:

1. Click Flag
2. Click 'It does not belong here.'
3. Click 'Off Topic'
4. See that appropriate target site isn't in list.
5. Click 'back'
6. Click 'Cancel'
7. Click 'Flag'
8. Click 'Other'
9. Type note, click 'Flag Question'

Comment: You do realize that if you have >3,000 reputation (maybe all?), clicking "it does not belong here" just takes you to the vote-to-close screen instead. If it's an old question where it might not get the close votes it needs, you should just use the "other" option in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

> 3- All sites.

We do not really need the ability to migrate to all sites. If somebody posts a question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) that really belongs to [bicycles.stackexchange.com](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), it should just be closed.

> 2- The sites that are loosely related to the site I'm on.

That's how it's currently done. The 5 sites that are currently shown might not be enough in 100 % of all cases that require migration, but it works fine most of the time.

> 1- The sites that I belong to.

That is just arbitrary and pointless. 5 close votes are required to close / migrate a question. If those 5 users vote for different actions, the majority decides. Implementing this suggestion would in all likelihood cause migration votes to 5 different sites.

Flag for moderator attention makes much more sense if you know about a site that would be a perfect fit for the question, but is not listed among the 5 default options, as the moderator can migrate the question directly (no voting process involved).

> I recognize it's easy enough to just add a note to the mods for the flag, but that's a terrible user experience right now: [...]

If you already know which these 5 sites are, you only need to follow the last three steps. That works for me.

Comment: A few points- 1) If a question is simply closed when it could be migrated, that's not a positive experience for the asker and reduces the likelihood that they'll stick around if they're new to the network.  2) I see that you participate on 15 SE sites.  What are the possible migration targets, without looking, for Mathematics?  I doubt you know.  3)  Option #2 isn't arbitrary.  I'd wager that proposed migration targets are most likely to sites in which the flagger participates.

Comment: @JacobG If it were possible to migrate to any site, then some users could possibly start asking questions on a random site, saying something like "Please migrate it, if this is not the right site." That is not what we would want, especially if the user's reasoning is "You have too much sites, and I cannot be bothered to see which one is the correct site."

Comment: @JacobG: I think the more relevant goal isn't so much to create avenues by which questions can be migrated to other sites, but rather to create awareness of the other sites among users.

Comment: @David: I think that having easy avenues to migrate questions is a mechanism to help raise awareness, but I understand not everyone might agree with that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think that's an exceptional case and certainly not likely enough to happen to arbitrarily close anything that doesn't belong.

Comment: @JacobG: AD 1: If somebody asks a question on Stack Overflow that would fit better on Programmers or SuperUser, it's a minor mistake and migration fixes it. However, if it belongs on bicycles, **he posted a bicycle question on a software development Q&A site**. Such behavior should simply not be rewarded by migration. Period. It shows that the poster did not put any effort in his questions and it encourages people to post their questions on Stack Overflow and just see where they get migrated to.

Comment: @JacobG: AD 2&3: I have no idea what the possible migration canidate on Mathematics are. This is because I have never asked nor answered a question on Mathematics, which makes me as competent as anyone else who has read the FAQ when it comes to deciding whether a questions belongs or not to Mathematics. Having signed up on Mathematics does not imply any participation. Likewise, participating on a site does not imply having an associated account.