# Why flagging a post as off-topic doesn't include crossvalidated?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, off-topic

So, I'm relatively new to stackexchange and mainly participate in R-related posts to SO and statistics questions on CrossValidated. I've noticed that when trying to flag a question as off-topic, if the post is on CrossValidated but should be on SO, there's an option to flag it as such but the reverse isn't true. Thus when someone posts a question to SO that is really about statistics and no so much about R, I'm not sure how to flag it.

I've read about the limitations to the flag interface here: [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) and here: [off-topic site list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96013/off-topic-site-list?lq=1). I realize a lot of what is posted on SO is not statistics-related, but it seems like it would be helpful to have the flagging interface be tag-dependent, maybe? So, questions tagged R (or another statistical language) in SO would be able to be easily flagged as relevant to CrossValidated.

Or, maybe I'm missing something obvious about how to suggest a question be moved from SO to CrossValidated.

Comment: Flag with `Other` reason

Comment: Also consider that being able to migrate all questions to all sides might lead to exploits "Oh, I'll just post my answer to Stack Overflow, they'll for sure migrate it to the right side."

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I think most of these types of off-topic posts come from new users, though, so they genuinely just don't know the difference between the sites.

Comment: Dup? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags

Comment: @Mat Nice find. Hadn't seen that.